# Pagination unique to a widget

Tags: wp-query, pagination

I am having troubles with pagination. It's widget. Every widget does have unique id . Say i have two widgets with pagination. If I cick page 2 of widget 2 then it will work but it will change the pagination of first one too.

```
$paged_id = $this->get_id();
$paged_query_var = 'paged'.$paged_id;
//var_dump($paged_id);
$paged_bottom = (get_query_var($paged_query_var)) ? absint(get_query_var($paged_query_var)) : 1;
$paged_bottom_args  = array(
  'format'    => '?paged'.$paged_id.'=%#%',
  'current'   => intval($paged_bottom),
  'total'     => intval($query->max_num_pages),
  'mid_size'  => $pagination_midsize,
  'prev_text' => '<i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i>',
  'next_text' => '<i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>',
);
echo paginate_links($paged_bottom_args);
```

this is what i tried but it does not work as get_query_var will not have variable in it. This is some thing dynamic so i am not able to set the variable for get_query_var using the filter.

Is there any way?

Comment: Does your widget 1 always returns to page 1 when you are changing pages on widget 2?

Comment: @VitautsStočka no both changes together as in widget 2. vice versa

Comment: Can you post full URL query string part when you have page 2 on widget 1 and change to page 2 on widget 2? I guess it has only one paged= arg with no id in it.

Comment: @VitautsStočka thanks for the idea up I mixed it with widget id, now it is working fine. thank you